# Vertically scrolling text with css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sass

I've just started to learn front-end development and I'm trying to figure out how to create a list of scrolling list that pauses every 20s.
Like the Greetings section in the header of this website where the greetings keep changing.
https://mynameismirko.it/
I tried to use use setTimeout to change the opacity but no success. Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [mcve]. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Right click on the element, and then select Inspect. The styles that changes should give you an indicator of how it's done. Use setInterval to change class or read up on  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame